# Emails not arriving to client's inbox. Server not on black list

Tags: email

I'm sending emails to my clients who are hosted on GoDaddy for both their website and email.  For some reason, my system's emails are no longer reaching their inbox.  My email server sends them alerts when an action is completed.  These alerts are posted in my system and my email server is sending these out, but there are no bounceback emails.

There have been no issues in the past year, but in the past two weeks the problem started cropping up.  My clients were forced to switched to a web-based email provider like Gmail, Hotmail, Yahoo to receive their alerts.  This is a temporary solution that works in the interim.

I contacted GoDaddy and they are indicating that I am not being blocked.  I also have a GoDaddy account and can confirm that my alerts aren't arriving in the inbox regardless of whatever safe sender items I employ in the webmail interface.  I even switched all the system's outbound emails to Plain Text, no luck.

Can anyone provide some insight and point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As you've already confirmed the messages can be received elsewhere the logical conclusion is that the problem exists at GoDaddy, so you need to try and get their help to debug this. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the basics:

Can your email server resolve the MX records for GoDaddy?

Can you make a telnet connection to port 25 of a GoDaddy MX from your email server?

Can you send an email to a GoDaddy recipient from the telnet session?

Your server doesn't have to be on a block list for the email to not go through. It could be a content filter on the recipient server or a junk email rule in the client settings.